# Mozilla installation issue

Tags: installation, add-apt-repository, mozilla

When I am installing firefox using apt-get command it throwing this error:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_27.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
```

Is there anyone who can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? Firefox is installed when you install ubuntu.

Comment: yes I am using ubuntu12.04LTS
Want to reinstall it.

Comment: Why would you want to reinstall it? Do you have internet?

Comment: Because I removed it by mistake. Now want to install it again but it is throwing error. Yes I have internet connection.

Comment: You are downloading a beta version of firefox from the ppa. Do you want to install the stable release instead?

Comment: oops... okk I think stable release will be good choice. How to install???

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the ppa for firefox you will first need to install [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge). To install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then remove the ppa using:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

This should display a message which says it is removing the ppa from the system and at the end:

```
PPA purged successfully
```

Then install the stable release of firefox using:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: @user234049: Please accept the answer if it has worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Updates` either by typing the same in dash or by keying in `ALT + F2` shortcut and then running the command `software-properties-gtk`.
Then goto the second tab `Other Software` from there you can manually remove the wrong `ppa` (personal package archive).
Then you can again try to install `Mozilla Firefox` either through `Ubuntu Software Center` or through terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for you help. But still my problem is not solved when I am giving command : 

sudo apt-get install firefox


It is throwing error : 
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_26.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Don't know what to do.